# Return instance of One to One Field

Tags: python, database, django, sqlite

I have a custom user below:

```
class ClubUser(models.Model): #added: Inherits from Django's existing User module.

  user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
  administrator = models.BooleanField()
  address = models.CharField(max_length = 100,blank=True, null=True)
  facebook = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
  twitter = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

  User.profile = property(lambda u : UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

I have gotten forms working where users register and they set the administrator field to true or false by checking a check box.

In another view method I want to check whether this administrator field is set to true, however, I do not know how to return an instance of my ClubUser object from a User object.

I know that I can get the currently logged in user object via user = user.request, however, I do not have access to my ClubUser fields from this object.

Any help will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `OneToOneField`s create a return link on the other model with the same name as the originating model.

```
request.user.clubuser
```